# React, how to memoize API Data called in reusable component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that opens the dialog to provide inputs:

```
function App() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={setToggle(true)}>Show Dialog</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the dialog component which is opened:

```
function Dialog() {

  return (
  <>
   <span>
     <div> Name: </div>
     <input type="text" />
   </span>
  <span>
     <div> Select: </div>
     <SelectionBox/>
   </span>
  </>
  );
}
export default Dialog;
```

Selection box component code is as following:

```
function SelectionBox() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
  const apiCalls = () => {
     service.getData1().then((data) => {
       service.getData2(data).then((opt) => {
         setOptions(opt);
       }).catch((e1) => {
         console.log(e1);
       });
     }).catch((e) => {
       console.log(e);
     });
     
  };

  return (
   <>
     <Select
      label="select"
      options={options}
      value={value} 
     />
   </>
  );

}
export default SelectionBox;
```

Selection box component calls two APIs to get and display the data in selection box. This API call takes time and I want to call the API only once when I open the dialog box and memoize that response for further dialog box actions. This select box can be re-used at some other place also and data is going to be same at all the places. How can I achieve this?

PS: I want to call the APIs when component is mounted. Also, not open to use any libraries.

Comment: You can read about `react-query`

Comment: When you wanna call `apiCalls`, on mount of `SelectionBox`?

Comment: @yousoumar : I want to call apis on mount.

Comment: @RishiMishra I pasted an answer. Have you looked at it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the help of an `useEffect` and `localStorage`. On every mount, you check if there is saved data inside `localStorage`, if yes use it, else you call your api, and store the result inside `localStorage`. Something like so:

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
function SelectionBox() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const apiCalls = () => {
      service.getData1().then((data) => {
          service
            .getData2(data)
            .then((opt) => {
              localStorage.setItem("options", JSON.stringify(opt));
              setOptions(opt);
            })
            .catch((e1) => {
              console.log(e1);
            });
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    };
    let opt;
    try {
      opt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("options"));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
    if (!Array.isArray(opt)) {
      apiCalls();
    } else {
      setOptions(opt);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Select label="select" options={options} value={value} />
    </>
  );
}
export default SelectionBox;
```